# Accent and case insensitive collation in Oracle with LIKE

Tags: java, database, oracle, sql-like, case-insensitive

I have found this answer useful:
[Accent and case insensitive COLLATE equivalent in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507504/accent-and-case-insensitive-collate-equivalent-in-oracle), but my question is regarding LIKE searching with a version 9 Oracle db.

I have tried a query like this:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE NLSSORT(column_name, 'NLS_SORT = Latin_AI')
LIKE NLSSORT('%somethingInDB%', 'NLS_SORT = Latin_AI')
```

but no results are ever returned.

I created a little Java file to test:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DbCollationTest
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
 {
  BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
  dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  dataSource.setUrl("url");
  dataSource.setUsername("usr");
  dataSource.setPassword("pass");

  Connection conn = null;
  PreparedStatement createStatement = null;
  PreparedStatement populateStatement = null;
  PreparedStatement queryStatement = null;
  PreparedStatement deleteStatement = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;

  try
  {
   conn = dataSource.getConnection();

   createStatement = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE CollationTestTable ( Name varchar(255) )");
   createStatement.execute();

   String[] names = { "pepe", "pépé", "PEPE", "MEME", "mémé", "meme" };
   int i = 1;

   for (String name : names)
   {
    populateStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CollationTestTable VALUES (?)");
    populateStatement.setString(1, name);
    populateStatement.execute();
   }

   queryStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM CollationTestTable WHERE NLSSORT(NAME, 'NLS_SORT = Latin_AI') LIKE NLSSORT('%pe%', 'NLS_SORT = Latin_AI')");
   rs = queryStatement.executeQuery();

   while (rs.next())
   {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
   }

   deleteStatement = conn.prepareStatement("DROP TABLE CollationTestTable");
   deleteStatement.execute();
  }
  finally
  {
   //DBTools.tidyUp(conn, null, rs);
   //DBTools.tidyUp(createStatement);
   //DBTools.tidyUp(populateStatement);
   //DBTools.tidyUp(queryStatement);
   //DBTools.tidyUp(deleteStatement);
  }
 }
}
```

I have not had any success googling, anyone have any solutions?

I want to perform a search on part of a name and return results that are matched using case and accent insensitivity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

one method would be to modify your session parameters `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_COMP`:

```
SQL> SELECT Name FROM CollationTestTable WHERE NAME LIKE '%pe%';

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pepe

SQL> alter session set nls_sort=Latin_AI;

Session altered

SQL> alter session set nls_comp=linguistic;

Session altered

SQL> SELECT Name FROM CollationTestTable WHERE NAME LIKE '%pe%';

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pepe
pépé
PEPE
```

As shown in [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380068/oracle-how-do-i-create-indexes-that-will-be-used-when-nlscomplinguistic-and-n), you cannot use the LIKE operator with `NLSSORT` (this is because, [NLSSORT returns a string of bytes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions099.htm#i78399) that will be used for sorting, and LIKE only works with charater strings)

**Update:** While setting the NLS parameters would be my first choice, you could also use built-in functions to achieve the same result. A couple of examples:

```
SQL> SELECT Name
  2    FROM CollationTestTable
  3   WHERE upper(convert(NAME, 'US7ASCII'))
  4         LIKE upper(convert('%pe%', 'US7ASCII'));

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pepe
pépé
PEPE

SQL> SELECT Name
  2    FROM CollationTestTable
  3   WHERE upper(translate(NAME, 'àâéèêìîòôùûÿ', 'aaeeeiioouuy'))
  4         LIKE upper(translate('%pe%', 'àâéèêìîòôùûÿ', 'aaeeeiioouuy'));

NAME
-----------------------------------
pepe
pépé
PEPE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there anyway of doing it without altering the session? Other queries in the same session may require the original NLS settings. Cheers.

Comment: @Ed: you could save the session parameters before running the query (select * from nls_session_parameters) then putting them back after the query.

Comment: I have been testing this and all looked good but am now told that NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP solution is only supported in version 10 r2. I need to support Oracle databases with min version 9. Is the only way I can perform the case and accent insensitive search is using functions?

Comment: @Ed: NLS_SORT=linguistic seems to be a 10g feature. You can still use the second method (SQL functions) in 9i.