# Ignore accent in the query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a query, that will compare values in `WHERE` clause.

The thing is, I got, sometime accents in some words.

And so, the words will not be the same, while it should be.

For example I got on my table `t_etab` :

```
1 | Collège
2 | Université
```

I want to get a line in `t_etab` doing this :

```
SELECT id_etab
from t_etab
where instr(UPPER('COLLEGE RANDOM                                   '),UPPER(lib_etab)) > 0;
```

But this will not get the `id 1`, as `lib_etab` will be `COLLÈGE` and not `COLLEGE`.

Is there a way to ignore accents, so my query return 1?

**edit : As said in the reladed question, we have to replace/translate all the char by ourself.**

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

As opposed to editing this answer, a much better (oracle oriented) one is available here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572781/3824902

*You'll need to coerce the query to an accent insensitive collation. You will also need to ensure both sides have the same collation, otherwise you may return further errors when running other comparisons.*

```
SELECT id_etab
from t_etab
where instr collate Latin1_General_CI_AI Like   
                                '%COLLEGE%' collate Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx*

Comment: Thanks for the answer . First : isn't this a little restrictive? Using a local encode? Second : I got error message on collate keyword. Are you sure I can use it in oracle? third : instr is a oracle function, not the field. I must compare `lib_etab` with a string. So, it isn't clear, what your answer must be.

Comment: This incorrect. It's not Oracle

Comment: @Zaphod Forgive me, I missed the Oracle tag and incorrectly assumed SQL. A better answer is linked.

Comment: Oracle runs SQL @Wolfish as does MySQL and SQL Server etc.. SQL is the language and there's slightly different extensions/deviations from the standard implemented by every relational database management system.

Comment: Indeed. This is the type of disadvantage that self-learning often shows. Perhaps a better term would have been MS-SQL.