# Compare Strings ignoring accents in SQL (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if there is an easy way to compare two text values ignoring the accents and upper case. Im working with an Oracle database.
I already searched for an answer but honestly I don't understand what they proposed in here [Accent and case insensitive collation in Oracle with LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572577/accent-and-case-insensitive-collation-in-oracle-with-like/1572781#1572781). I tried that and it didn't work for me. Basically all I want to do is two compare to text values like 'pepé' and 'pepe' and obtain true as answer.

is it possible to do it without the LIKE instruction?

Thank You!

Comment: Are you trying to compare the strings for equality ignoring case and accents?  Or to do a `LIKE` comparison between them ignoring case and accents?  Setting `nls_sort` and `nls_comp` as the answer you linked to suggests would appear to solve your problem.  Can you explain what it is that you don't understand?  Have you tried running the two `alter session` statements?  Did it not work?

Comment: @JustinCave basically what I want to do is to make a Join by the name of a city, but in the data that I have the same city sometimes appear with accent and sometimes don't, so it recognize them as two different cities. I can't change the data.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `nls_sort` and `nls_comp` in your session and running the query?  It would appear that this would accomplish what you want in which case this is a duplicate of the question you identified.  If that doesn't resolve the problem, can you help us understand what specifically does not work for you?

Comment: @JustinCave Well, I'm kind of knew in SQL so maybe I'm a little bit lost, I'm making the consults over an user which I don't have permission to create tables only to consult them. So I'm not quite sure if I will be able to change the parameters, Is there any way else?

Comment: Have you tried running the commands?  If you can create a session (log in to the database), you should have permission to change your session's NLS settings.

Answer (score 12):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( value ) AS
SELECT 'pepé' FROM DUAL;

-- Not necessary to create an index but it can speed things up.
CREATE INDEX value_without_accent_idx
  ON TABLE_NAME ( CONVERT( value, 'US7ASCII' ) );
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONVERT( value, 'US7ASCII' ) = 'pepe';
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE
-----
pepé
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I'm making the consults over an user which I don't have permission to create tables only to consult them. How can I do this without changing the configuration or create tables?

Comment: Just use the query on the appropriate table (without having the index). The index isn't necessary as it will just pre-calculate the converted values making if faster to generate the results - if you can't do that then it will still work but just slower.

Comment: Perfect! that was exactly what I looked for. Hate down and Huge thanks!

Comment: If you convert the word São, the output will be S?o. How could be improved to return Sao instead?

Answer (score 6):

use the `nlssort` function in the following way:

```
select * from <your_table> where utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(<inspected_column>, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))) like 'pe%';
```

The nlssort call transforms accented characters to their linguistic bases and ignores case in comparisons.

Original source is [this article](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1117030?start=0&tstart=0) (verified on 12c).

Answer (score 2):

This works for `Ç` and the rest of characters in PT-BR (Portuguese - Brazil):

```
SELECT CONVERT( 'ÃÕÑ ÁÉÍ Ç', 'SF7ASCII' ) FROM DUAL;
Result: **AON AEI C**
```

Check your database version:

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;
   Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
    PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    "CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production"
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is english speaking only

Comment: This is the one, SF7ASCII converts "á" to "a" while US7ASCII converts "á" to "?".

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1117030?start=0&tstart=0) you can do the following:

```
select * from your_table 
where upper(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(your_column, 'nls_sort=binary_ai')))) like upper('%word%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle 12.2 there is the *collate* keyword which can be used with *binary_ci* for a case insensitive search and with *binary_ai* for both case and accent insensitive. This is also a more index-friendly method, but I am not aware of the exact details regarding indexes.

SELECT age
FROM persons
WHERE name = 'pepe' COLLATE binary_ai

Matches on: Pepé

Source:
https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-do-case-insensitive-and-accent-insensitive-search-in-oracle-database

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the following blog:
https://eduardolegatti.blogspot.com/2013/04/ignorando-caracteres-acentuados.html

The @AJPerez reply is valid but you might have problem by using it with LIKE operator.
As @Just Cavin suggested, execute it before your query: (Versions after 10g R2)

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='WEST_EUROPEAN_AI'; -- Accent Insensitive
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP='LINGUISTIC'; -- Case Insensitive