# Compare street name

Tags: java, spring, oracle, performance, ibatis

I use Java , Spring, Ibatis, Oracle data base .

Inside that database we have 1 table is **Street** with *10 million records*, the important column is *street_name*.

From GUI, I have to search company by street, for example : the street name input is Sch**o**nburgstrasse but the correct data inside DB is : Sch**ö**nburgstrasse (German)

You can see that, the main different is : **o** and **ö** . And for sure I can't find this record by the SQL :

```
Select * from Street where street_name = 'Schonburgstrasse';
```

The rules are :

- I can't change the data base schema any more.
- I can't get 10M records to normalization one by one. After that compare data

(Normalization means , I will have function to convert From : Sch**ö**nburgstrasse, To : Sch**o**nburgstrasse)

- I have to take care for performance problem.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: especially when DB's are involved, normalisation is something completely different. if your data in the db is with ö, then o should not return anything, because it is wrong

Comment: @B001 he wants (on DB level) an equals where "o".equals("ö") returns true ..

Comment: @Stultuske : thanks, you got my idea. But I have to returns true for this case. And not only DB level, I can change anywhere. In this case DB should return nothing, but I have to return this data by somehow.

Comment: Please clarify a couple of things - how many street records do you have (10M != 10 billion), and why can't your users enter the correct street name? And what should happen if a user enters "Schoenburgstrasse" (using "oe" as a replacement for "ö" - the usual approach for writing Umlauts in ASCII?

Comment: 10 billion? More than humans on earth? Is this for real, because if you actually have 1000 records and not 1 billion, an unacceptable solution might become acceptable.

Comment: @BIZ yes, I understand what you are trying to do, but it is ridiculous and you shouldn't try this. hog and hög are not the same, neither would it be correct if it was spelled hôg.

Comment: if you´re using a `12c` database you might be able to include the new [Fuzzy Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-098F287A-DD02-42E1-B685-B1E4ED108FBA.htm#CCAPP9071) build in there

Comment: You can use translate() in oracle, but that will do that your indexes won't work. If I had 10 billions in an Oracle Database just for search a simple text, I would use another kind o database. Such: Elasticseach, Solr.

Comment: maybe one of this links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689157/compare-strings-ignoring-accents-in-sql-oracle or https://blogs.oracle.com/searchtech/oracle-text-and-accented-characters can help you

Comment: Sorry if i make you confused. Updated. But how many records is not really important, the important thing is : I can't get one by one and normalization them.

Comment: I still didn't find my expected answer, do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the Oracle [SOUNDEX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions148.htm) command, so the query will look like this:

```
Select * from Street where soundex(street_name) = soundex('Schonburgstrasse');
```

Comment: This will return false positives: 
`with street as (select 'Schönburgstrasse' as street_name from dual)
Select * from Street where soundex(street_name) = soundex('Schanburgstrasse');`

which might (or might not) cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but look like soundex just support English, my DB is German. And I'm not really sure for the result correct or not for all cases.

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle Text](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/CCAPP/querying-with-oracle-text.htm#CCAPP9171) provides extensive capabilities for handling umlauts etc. In short:

- create a fulltext index on your column (using a custom lexer)
- search with the `contains()` operator instead of `like`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't create the index for this column. And I can't use contains(). Sorry I didn't talk about that before. Any other idea ?

Comment: If you're not allowed to add indices / use `CONTAINS`, you might have to perform the search outside of the database; ElasticSearch seems like the obvious choice.