# Oracle SQL join using like and cast to varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, join, casting

I need to `join` few tables. One of columns has a diacritics (eg. áíé...) but the second one has no diacritics and in some records is a postfix. Let's say:

```
Table A:                               Table B:

code  |  name  |  surname              name     |  username
-------------------------              --------------------
1234  |  John  |  Doé                  Doe      |  Doe
5678  |  Jane  |  Smith                Doe      |  DoeJ
9012  |  Tom   |  Novák                Dean Doe |  DoeD
```

I need to `join` these two tables on the `surname` and `username` and I need to show all records from table B that can match to record from Table A. And I have a list of specific `code`-s from Table A.
So my `select` should return something like this, if my list of codes will be only the 1234:

```
A.name  |  A.surname  |  B.username
-----------------------------------
John    |  Doé        |  Doe
John    |  Doé        |  DoeJ
John    |  Doé        |  DoeD
```

Now I have this `select`:

```
select A.name, A.surname, B.username
  from (select column_value as code
    from SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('1234', '5678', '9012', '3456')) t
right join tableA A on t.code = A.code
join tableB B
  on replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(p.prijmeni, 'Ě', 'E'), 'Š', 'S'), 'Č', 'C'), 'Ř', 'R'), 'Ž', 'Z'), 'Ý', 'Y'), 'Á', 'A'), 'Í', 'I'), 'É', 'E'), 'Ú', 'U'), 'Ů', 'U'), 'Ď', 'D'), 'Ň', 'N'), 'Ó', 'O'), 'Ť', 'T')
    like (B.username || '%')
where t.code is not null;
```

And the result is only one record:

```
A.name  |  A.surname  |  B.username
-----------------------------------
John    |  Doé        |  Doe
```

When I delete (comment) the `t.code is not null` in `where` clause, I have partially correct result:

```
A.name  |  A.surname  |  B.username
-----------------------------------
John    |  Doé        |  Doe
null    |  null       |  DoeJ
null    |  null       |  DoeD
```

But there are hundreds of records in the table B which I don't want in my result.

Can anyone help me? I know, that the concept is wrong, but it's not my work and I need to correct it now.

Comment: maybe use a REPLACE function to swap out the letters prior to the compare in the WHERE clause

Comment: @Randy: I tried it, but it doesn't work. But query is a bit faster, so I let it there and I editted my first post of this topis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the '%' to the wrong side, this should work:

```
select A.name, A.surname, B.username
  from (select column_value as code
    from SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('1234', '5678', '9012', '3456')) t
right join tableA A on t.code = A.code
join tableB B
  on B.username
  LIKE replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(p.prijmeni, 'Ě', 'E'), 'Š', 'S'), 'Č', 'C'), 'Ř', 'R'), 'Ž', 'Z'), 'Ý', 'Y'), 'Á', 'A'), 'Í', 'I'), 'É', 'E'), 'Ú', 'U'), 'Ů', 'U'), 'Ď', 'D'), 'Ň', 'N'), 'Ó', 'O'), 'Ť', 'T') || '%'
where t.code is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
on B.username LIKE utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(A.surname, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))
```

in your join condition.
   The nlssort call transforms accented characters to their linguistic bases and ignores case in comparisons.

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35697017/). However, the OP query also suffered from another problem, so I am not sure whether to flag a duplicate.