# Is there any way to skip only letter(s) while comparing two table column values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

If you could help in my situation I would be glad.
The case is I have two tables. In both tables there is a column for person names.
However, inside these names there are unusual names as well.
Like table1.column_names has "MO'YDIN", table2.column_names has "MOYDIN". Or " КУШАКЎВИЧ" -  "КУШАКУВИЧ". I should skip these kind of signs in oracle procedure.
Thanks to all your help in advance.

Comment: Using a case and accent insensitive collation?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't figure out what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

See if SOUNDEX() will work for your environment and character set:

```
SELECT 'TRUE'
FROM dual
WHERE SOUNDEX('MO''YDIN') = SOUNDEX('MOYDIN');


'TRUE'
------
TRUE  
1 row selected.
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for the OP's second set of sample data that has accents [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef462/2).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [`CONVERT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35689487/1509264) to remove the accents and then use replace or `REGEXP_REPLACE` to strip the punctuation:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON ( CONVERT( REGEXP_REPLACE( t1.column1, '[[:punct:]]' ), 'US7ASCII' )
            = CONVERT( t2.column2, 'US7ASCII' ) )
```

Or you can use `NLSSORT` to remove the accents:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON (
         NLSSORT( REPLACE(t1.column1,''''), 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI' )
         = NLSSORT(t2.column2, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')
       );
```

Or, you can use the `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_COMP` session parameters:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI;

SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON ( REPLACE( t1.column1, '''' ) = t2.column2 );
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( column1 ) AS
SELECT N'MO''YDIN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT N'КУШАКЎВИЧ' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( column2 ) AS
SELECT N'MOYDIN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT N'КУШАКУВИЧ' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

```
|   COLUMN1 |   COLUMN2 |
|-----------|-----------|
|   MO'YDIN |    MOYDIN |
| КУШАКЎВИЧ | КУШАКУВИЧ |
```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef462/11)*