# Oracle SQL select query that return results with diacritis inside the name

Tags: sql, oracle, select, diacritics

Hello I have a Java app that runs an Oracle SQL select query that returns some results.

This is the select:

```
select a,b,c where a='%ruicanescu%'
```

This returns only results where the name is exactly 'ruicanescu' but I would like also to return for example: 'ruicănescu' and other diacritics inside the name. Can someone give me an example ? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare Strings ignoring accents in SQL (ORACLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689157/compare-strings-ignoring-accents-in-sql-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CONVERT`:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONVERT(a, 'US7ASCII') LIKE '%ruicanescu%';
```

Or you can set the `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_COMP` session parameters to accent insensitive matching:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP='LINGUISTIC';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='BINARY_AI';

SELECT a, b, c
FROM   table_name
WHERE  a LIKE '%ruicanescu%';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b, c) AS
SELECT 'ruicănescu', 1, 1  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ruicanescu', 2, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | A | B | C |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ruicănescu | 1 | 1 |
> | ruicanescu | 2 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f90d995f16f887a29510dd4cff480458)*